# Why timepicker can not be downgraded when choosing a date other than today?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

My html code like this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datepicker' data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type='text' class="form-control" id='timepicker' data-date-format="HH:mm" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="btnSubmit">
    Submit
</button>
```

My JavaScript code like this:

```
$(function () {    
    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker();

    $('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
        minDate: moment().startOf('minute').add(300, 'm'),
    });
});
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    value = document.getElementById('datetimepicker').value;
    console.log(value)
});
```

Demo like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8jpmkcr5/89/

If I click the timepicker and click the decrement hour icon, it does not work. I know it happens because this code : `minDate: moment().startOf('minute').add(300, 'm')`. I want the code to work only on this day. Other than today the code does not work

How can I do it?

Comment: Is there no one can help?

Comment: In which situation decrement operation should run?

Comment: @Ananth Cool, Other than today. For example tomorrow it can be clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#datepicker` and `#timepicker` are **unrelated**, they are **fully independent**, 
is up to you to ***relate*** them. You can dinamically set `minDate` of `#timepicker` using [`minDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate) function.

You can add a listner for [`dp.change`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange) event and enable or disable the `minDate` for the `#timepicker` chceking if the selected day is current day (using momentjs [`isSame`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/)).

You have to add [`minDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate) option also to `#datepicker` if you want to disable past dates, as you stated in the comments.

Here a working sample:

```js
$(function () {    
  $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment().startOf('day')
  }).on('dp.change', function(e){
    if( e.date && e.date.isSame(moment(), 'd') ){
      var min = moment().startOf('minute').add(300, 'm');
      $('#timepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(min);
    } else {
      $('#timepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(false);
    }
  });
  
  $('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment().startOf('minute').add(300, 'm'),
  });
});


$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
   value = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
   console.log(value)
   valueTime = document.getElementById('timepicker').value;
   console.log(valueTime)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datepicker' data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" />
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type='text' class="form-control" id='timepicker' data-date-format="HH:mm" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="btnSubmit">
    Submit
</button>
```

Please note that, as stated before, `#datepicker` and `#timepicker` are unrelated, so with the `#timepicker` you are simply selecting a time, that defaults to current day (no automatic relationship with the selected day using `#datepicker`).

Comment: Date can only be selected at least today. If user chooses yesterday, it can not

Comment: @SuccessMan updated my code adding `minDate` to `#datepicker`, now you can not select past dates.

Comment: Yes it works. But there is still a problem. If i choose tomorrow (03-08-2017) then I click downgrade on the time, it can not. The time should not be downgraded for just today

Comment: Are you sure? I cannot reproduce this issue with the code in my snippet. If I select tomorrow (03-08-2017) then I can select everything in the `#timepicker`. The `$('#timepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(null);` in the `dp.change` listner resets `minDate` option for the `#timepicker` if the selected day is not the current day.

Comment: Nono, I'm trying to say that, in my opinion the code in the snippet is fine and you cannot _"downgrade time"_ only if you select current day in the `#datepicker`. I can't reproduce the problem you are describing in your comment (_If i choose tomorrow (03-08-2017) then I click downgrade on the time, it can not. The time should not be downgraded for just today_)

Comment: So you mean it can be done. But you have not found the best solution yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150825/discussion-between-vincenzoc-and-success-man).

Comment: to clear the minDate option, pass false instead of null
see here
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate

Comment: @VincenzoC, There is still an error. If submit your code, there exist error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Comment: @Mohammad, Okay. Thanks bro

Comment: @VincenzoC, Your code still has bugs. For example now on 16 August at 9 pm. As it appears that the date of 17 August at 2 am. But the demo in your code is August 16 at 2 am

Comment: @VincenzoC, Do you have a solution?

Comment: @SuccessMan I'm on mobile, I've edited the submit part of my snippet (btw note that it was not relevant to your original question, I've simply copied your code)

Comment: @VincenzoC, Ok. What about my second question on my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the input to today only, why are you trying to set a limit on the *time* picker? You should be setting the limit on the *date* picker

Comment: I do not know. So I asked. If you know that, please answer with the code. Let me easily understand