# how to set mindate for time input according to another date input in Eonasdan datetime picker?

Tags: javascript, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have two inputs, one for date, and the other for time. I want to link them together where the minimum date is "today", and the minimum time is "now" if the date selected is today.

js:

```
$('#operation-date').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/Y',
    useCurrent: true,
    minDate: moment().startOf('d')
});

$('#operation-time').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT',
    useCurrent: true,
    minDate: moment()
});
```

the minimum time will always be "now" regardless of the selected date, so how I can link them together?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45428366/4131048), I think you can use the same code of the accepted answer (you just have to change the value of the `minDate`).

Comment: @VincenzoC thanks, actually when we want to disable the minDate property, the that should be passed to `minDate()` is false not null

Comment: I've edited the linked answer using `false` instead of `null`. The snippet worked even using `minDate(null)`, but `minDate(false)` sounds more correct. Consider upvoting, if you find the linked solution useful.

Answer (score 0):

we should change the minDate option of the time picker according to the change of date picker

```
$('#operation-date').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/Y',
    minDate: moment().startOf('day')
}).on('dp.change', function(e){
    if( e.date && e.date.isSame(moment(), 'd') ){
        var min = moment().startOf('minute');
        $('#operation-time').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(min);
    } else {
        $('#operation-time').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(false);
    }
});

$('#operation-time').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT',
    minDate: moment().startOf('minute')
});
```